# WiFi Extender gives my MBP the WiFi Exclamation Mark

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I have a wifi extender (TP-Link TL-WR700N).  It works great for iPhones, iPads, Windows laptops, and Android devices.  However whenever my MBP (running Mavericks) switches to it from the main network, I get the ! and lose internet.  If I then tell my MBP to forget the network and reconnect to the extender, it works fine... until I move back in range of the main network, at which point I get the ! again and lose internet.

I'm quite well versed in networking, and was going to post this on SuperUser, but since this is very Mac specific I figured I'd start here.  Also, I'm stumped as to what mechanism in the OSX internals could be causing this.

Comment: Do the main router and the extender use the same SSID? Are they on the same subnet (I would assume they have to be, but...). And to be sure, the extender solely acts as a bridge, it doesn't have a DHCP server running?

Comment: Yes, same SSID.  Yes, same subnet.  And yes, the extender is configured as per this article - http://www.tplink.ca/en/article/?id=390.  Seems I'm not the only one though - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5691811.  The last post describes the exact issue I'm having as well.